# php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll not loading. Configuring ms sql server in php 7.1.0

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

[image: Php Version][image]I am trying to configure ms sql server database plugin in php 7.1.0 wamp server. I have downloaded windows 10 pr0 ms sql server php plugins from microsodt web site and placed in C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.22\ext . and modified the php_ini file with these extensions name and enabled odbc driver also .. Still i am getiing this issue,

```
> [20-Dec-2018 07:10:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library
> 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll' - The
> specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
> [20-Dec-2018 07:10:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll'
> - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [20-Dec-2018 07:10:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library
> 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll' - The
> specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
> [20-Dec-2018 07:10:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.22/ext/php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll'
> - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
;extension=php_enchant.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phpdbg_webhelper.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

Comment: Show what you've added in `php.ini`

Comment: Added extension , i dont know how to share full file. @D.Dimitrov

Comment: Try to comment out this two lines: `
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll`

Comment: Please, execute <?php phpinfo();?>. Is there a section with name pdo_sqlsrv (if you use PDO) and/or sqlsrv (without PDO)?

Comment: you only need `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
and extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll`

Comment: Did you download odbc driver for Sql Server? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50420

Comment: @Zhorov , Yes i have executed . Yes, i saw that pdo_sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support and version is  4.1.4.9021

Comment: @McBern , extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll  is it enough to make the connection from php to ms sql server

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian OK. Write a simple script and try to connect.

Comment: @McBern , i am already having odbc 16 in my machine

Comment: @McBern Thanks a lot...It is working for me....I have wasted my time by seeing nts error log messages

Comment: No problem....,